# How to call .UseStaticWebAssets() on WebApplicationBuilder?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I have a problem similar to the one outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58862932/blazor-server-static-files-dont-link-in-non-dev-environments).

When using custom environments while running locally, some files are not being loading (resulting in 404s, etc).

#### Question: How can I call `.UseStaticWebAssets()` using the `WebApplicationBuilder`?

In my program.cs, I tried adding some code to call `.UseStaticWebAssets()` like below, but I'm seeing the error `ConfigureWebHost() is not supported by WebApplicationBuilder.Host. Use the WebApplication returned by WebApplicationBuilder.Build() instead`.

```cs
// program.cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Host.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder => 
    {
        builder.UseStaticWebAssets();
    });

    // etc...
}
```

If I try using the `WebHost` prop on the aforementioned builder, I see compiler errors when trying to call the `UseStaticWebAssets()` method.

Comment: Do you need to use the dotnet 6 style minimal hosting model? Have you tried using the previous generic host style? [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#apps-migrating-to-60-dont-need-to-use-the-new-minimal-hosting-model)

Comment: @chadnt, if possible, I'd prefer to use the dotnet 6 minimal style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same issue, and found a workaround [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38212). Basically this gets around the exception; seems like this will be fixed in .NET 7.

```
builder.WebHost.UseWebRoot("wwwroot").UseStaticWebAssets();
```

Good luck!